# MVC design issue - roles of each component

Tags: model-view-controller

This is our first time using this pattern (we're not even sure that this pattern is suitable for this project), and me and my mates have a couple of questions.
We're designing a simple applications for displaying files with regards to permissions.

1. Suppose "Joe" is currently logged in to the system, where would be the correct place to save "Joe" as the active user?
2. What are the roles of the controller in this context? Suppose "Joe" wants to log in to the system. He enters his password and clicks log on, should the view validate the details directly with the Model? or should it ask the controller to do it for him?
3. Suppose that the login is successful, what should happen now? Should the View listen as an Observer to the model and wait for a response that the login is correct and then switch windows? or should the Controller have a method called `boolean ValidateLogin()` which the view calls and acts accordingly?

As you can see we're very confused, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first question may need clarification. By "save" do you mean a specific model operation as a result of a UI action? If so, that's a Controller function that talks to the model. Or if you mean "maintains Joe as the active user" then it's a feature of the session, which I'd regard as a Controller responsibility.

Comment: @halfer Each user, upon logging in, is shown all files for which he has permission to see. Now, suppose the model has a method getFiles(User user) which returns a list of files 'user' has permissions to see. Who should supply 'user'? should the model know who the active user is? should the controller know who the active user is?

Comment: Right, gotcha: the model should definitely **not** know who the active user is. This should be maintained and read by the controller, and supplied to a model method (the separation of this helps with unit testing). Your method is fine: `getFiles(User user)` in the model means that something has to supply `user` to it - which is the controller's job. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554149/472495) of mine may also help, in relation to dealing with user security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Session / Database / Configuration File (is this a single or multiple user system?)
2. In some web frameworks*: the view passes the login data to controller, passed to model which would validate, return the result to controller, and give the correct view as response. Surely it's also fine if the view wants to directly validate the data to the model, but IMO view-model communication should never have any logic involved, only data update notification.
3. I think it's partially answered in answer 2 above. The controller should be able to destroy/change the login view though (when the login successful, normally the view should change accordingly).

*This is because in web application, usually view cannot directly talk to model, as opposed in desktop application. This is still an MVC, only a variation called MVA.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, I suggest you use this project [MembershipStarterKit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit) to start with.

It has samples that do basic authentifacation and role management.

It also use the .Net membership provider so that you don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: This assumes that the OPs are interested in ASP.net MVC - I suspect they're just interested in the MVC design pattern.

Comment: @halfer Sorry, I haven't noticed that the tag was only MVC

Answer (score 0):

1. Store it in session
2. Any client side validation can be done by the view directly with the model(Through [DataAnnotations](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)). And for database calls it goes through the contoller
3. On successful login, controller will render the corresponding view